# Не работает запись в SQL. Android 5.1.1. Java

Tags: java, android, sql, база-данных, android-studio

Почему-то не работает запись в sql. Вот мой код:

> activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Посмотреть" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickAdd"
        android:text="Добавить" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.rost.myapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(1);
    }
    public void onClickAdd (View v) {
        db = getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase("words.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String edtext = ed.getText().toString();
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name TEXT, age INTEGER)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO users VALUES (edtext, 23);");
        db.close();
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        db = getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase("words.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name TEXT, age INTEGER)");
        Cursor query = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users;", null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if(query.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String name = query.getString(0);
                int age = query.getInt(1);
                textView.append("Name: " + name + " Age: " + age + "\n");
            }
            while(query.moveToNext());
        }
        query.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам нашел решение. Надо вместо

```
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO users VALUES (edtext, 23);");
```

делать так:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('"+edtext+"', 23);");
```